# Android AdMob problem showing graphics

Tags: android, admob

I'm facing weird problem while implementing AdMob into my application. The problem is that ads are not showing at all or if they will (sometimes, but it is rather rare), the left image on it still doesn't (there is question mark like on web page when can't open a picture).

I'm using the newest jar file from AdMob site. Any ideas, how to make them working properly?

PS. It happens on real device, on emulator everything is ok.

Comment: That ads are only showing rather rare at the beginning is normal. You can check in your AdMob Account whether a request for an ad was made.

Comment: It's normal that ad can't load it's image?

Comment: No it's normal that it doesn't always load ads. I thought you were asking about to issues. Not showing ads at all and not showing the image.

Comment: No no :-) When ad will be loaded it shows question mark insteadof it's left image, and if it won't load at all it shows question mark on left of ad area, but logcat always inform me that ad was loaded without any errors, it even shows me url of the ad.

Comment: Did you find what the problem was ?

Comment: The problem was probably my modded Android system. I've noticed that other apps have problems with showing adds too.